# Doc, ppt, xls mime type

Tags: android

I try to open **doc, ppt, xls** and **pfg** files with app installed via intent. For **pdf** I use `i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");`
but if I do following:

```
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/doc");
```

I receive exception, saying that there are no apps, that can handle intent. What am I doing wrong?
I've got QuickOffice installed, so I think it could open file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php) to the 'official' mime types for Microsoft Office files.  You'll probably have better luck if you use "application/msword" in place of "application/doc".

You can also have the OS try to determine the appropriate mime type for a file:

```
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
```

Hopefully any application that registers a mime type that it can handle will cause the mime type map to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get exact mime type from file path or URL is:

```
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url);
```